# I'm building a time slot api in laravel it gives us response but i need something like this

Tags: php, api, laravel-8

**The user wants to see for a specific timezone, how many coaches are available.**

Example API 1: Consider user A coming from the timezone UST and wants to get the list of coaches. So, the coaches list to be prepared based on the UST timezones ( convert the coaches data to show in the UST timezone and list it as a 1 hour time slot ).
e.g.:

```
{
  "zone": "UST",
  "coaches": [
    {
      "user_id": "123456",
       "name": "Amit Yadav",
      "time_slots": {
        "Monday" : [
        {
          "start_time": "03:30:00",
          "end_time": "04:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "04:30:00",
          "end_time": "05:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "05:30:00",
          "end_time": "06:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "06:30:00",
          "end_time": "07:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "07:30:00",
          "end_time": "08:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "08:30:00",
          "end_time": "09:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "09:30:00",
          "end_time": "10:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "10:30:00",
          "end_time": "11:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "11:30:00",
          "end_time": "12:00:00"
        }
      ],
        "Tuesday" : [
        {
          "start_time": "03:30:00",
          "end_time": "04:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "04:30:00",
          "end_time": "05:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "05:30:00",
          "end_time": "06:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "06:30:00",
          "end_time": "07:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "07:30:00",
          "end_time": "08:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "08:30:00",
          "end_time": "09:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "09:30:00",
          "end_time": "10:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "10:30:00",
          "end_time": "11:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "11:30:00",
          "end_time": "12:00:00"
        }
      ],
        "Wednesday" : [
        {
          "start_time": "03:30:00",
          "end_time": "04:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "04:30:00",
          "end_time": "05:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "05:30:00",
          "end_time": "06:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "06:30:00",
          "end_time": "07:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "07:30:00",
          "end_time": "08:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "08:30:00",
          "end_time": "09:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "09:30:00",
          "end_time": "10:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "10:30:00",
          "end_time": "11:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "11:30:00",
          "end_time": "12:00:00"
        }
      ],
        "Friday" : [
        {
          "start_time": "03:30:00",
          "end_time": "04:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "04:30:00",
          "end_time": "05:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "05:30:00",
          "end_time": "06:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "06:30:00",
          "end_time": "07:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "07:30:00",
          "end_time": "08:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "08:30:00",
          "end_time": "09:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "09:30:00",
          "end_time": "10:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "10:30:00",
          "end_time": "11:30:00"
        },
        {
          "start_time": "11:30:00",
          "end_time": "12:00:00"
        }
      ]
      
      }
    }
  ]
}

**my response coming like this how to fix** 

{
    "status": 200,
    "coaches": {
        "Amit Yadav": {
            "time_slots": {
                "Monday": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ],
                "Tuesday": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ],
                "Wednesda": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ],
                "Thursday": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ],
                "Friday": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ],
                "Saturday": [
                    {
                        "start_time": "9:00",
                        "end_time": "10:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "10:00",
                        "end_time": "11:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "11:00",
                        "end_time": "12:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "12:00",
                        "end_time": "1:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "1:00",
                        "end_time": "2:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "2:00",
                        "end_time": "3:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "3:00",
                        "end_time": "4:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "start_time": "4:00",
                        "end_time": "5:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        
            }
        }
    }
}

my controller function is  --


 public function all_coaches_availablity(Request $req)
        {
            $timezone = $req->post('timezone');


            $data1 = Customer::select('id','coach_name','time_zone','day_of_week','start_time','end_time')->Where('time_zone',$timezone)->get();
       
                $data=[];
              
                    foreach($data1 as $res)
                    {
                        if($res->time_zone ==$timezone)
                        {
                           
                            $day_of_week = $res->day_of_week;
                           

                            $data[$res->coach_name]['time_slots'][$day_of_week] = $this->getTimeSlot(60, $res->start_time, $res->end_time);


                        }else{
                        $date = new \DateTime($res->start_time, new \DateTimeZone($res->time_zone));
                        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
                        $sdt =  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

                        $date = new \DateTime($res->end_time, new \DateTimeZone($res->time_zone));
                        $date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
                        $new_timezone = config('app.timezone');
                        
                        $edt =  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
                        
                            $day_of_week   = $res->day_of_week;
                            $data['zone']  =  $new_timezone; 
                            //$data['coaches']['name'] =  $res->coach_name; 
                                
                            $data['time_slots'][$day_of_week] = $this->getTimeSlot(60, $sdt, $edt);

                        }

                        

                    }
                   
               
                return response()->json(['status'=>200,'coaches'=>$data]);
        }


This is my Traits function


function getTimeSlot($interval, $start_time, $end_time)
{
    $start = new \DateTime($start_time);
    $end = new \DateTime($end_time);
    $startTime = $start->format('H:i:s');
    $endTime = $end->format('H:i:s');
    $i=0;
    $time = [];
    while(strtotime($startTime) <= strtotime($endTime)){
        $start = $startTime;
        $end = date('H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$interval.' minutes',strtotime($startTime)));
        $startTime = date('H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$interval.' minutes',strtotime($startTime)));
        $i++;
        if(strtotime($startTime) <= strtotime($endTime)){

            $start =  date("g:i", strtotime($start));
            $end   =  date("g:i", strtotime($end));

            $time[$i]['start_time'] = $start;
            $time[$i]['end_time'] = $end;
            
        }
    }
    return array_values($time);
}

I'm building a time slot api in laravel it gives us response but i need something like this
```

Answer (score 0):

What is UST timezone?
Did you mean UTC?
How does the user enter their timezone?

You need to explain what the User asking for and what you want the user to receive.

That is what specifically does the user enter?
What specifically does the user see when they get the results. 
Time slots are just that.  Value is not from time - to time 
Value is 0 not used or 1 used.

I would keep it simple.
The coach table (24 time slots per day of week, value is 0 or 1)

```
TABLE `coaches` 
  `id` int(11)
  `coach` varchar(32)
  `timezone` char(32)
  `DOW` int(11)
  `timeslot0` int(11)
  `timeslot1` int(11)
  `timeslot2` int(11)
  `timeslot3` int(11)
  `timeslot4` int(11)
  `timeslot5` int(11)
  `timeslot6` int(11)
  `timeslot7` int(11)
  `timeslot8` int(11)
  `timeslot9` int(11)
  `timeslot10` int(11)
  `timeslot11` int(11)
  `timeslot12` int(11)
  `timeslot13` int(11)
  `timeslot14` int(11)
  `timeslot15` int(11)
  `timeslot16` int(11)
  `timeslot17` int(11)
  `timeslot18` int(11)
  `timeslot19` int(11)
  `timeslot20` int(11)
  `timeslot21` int(11)
  `timeslot22` int(11)
  `timeslot23` int(11)
```

If you explain what the API does, I could continue. 
Your current explanation is insufficient.

The query would be